# what happens as x goes to 0 when the second term would go to infinity?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

As in title

I have a concrete example thou:

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}x\left(1+\frac{4}{x^2}\right)^{\frac{1}2}$$

It's obvious that the second term $\left(1+\frac{4}{x^2}\right)^{\frac{1}2}$ would go to infinity, however, the first term tends to go to $0$. I know that $0\times\infty$ is not defined or indeterminate. But what about in this case? I tend to say that the limit would still be infinity. But is there a proper definition for situations like this?

Comment: $0\cdot\infty$ is one of the standard indeterminate forms.  It should be covered in every calculus text.

Comment: What steps did you take to conclude that the limit is $\infty$? Without that information, we cannot help you.

Comment: Maybe you can try to put the $x$ inside the square root ? ;-)

Comment: @Angel i just did term by term, $\lim_{x\to 0}x=0, \lim_{x\to 0}(1+\frac{4}{x^2})^{1/2}=\infty$

Comment: @Surb im an idiot. thatd make it $\infty$ i woudlnt have this problem then

Comment: You have already said that. But how do deduce from that that your limit is $\infty$?

Comment: @JerryHolmes Nice attempt, but you cannot do it term-by-term when limits with $\infty$ are involved. This is in essence one of the limit theorems. Distributing the limit to the individual terms assumes that each limit exists and is finite. So you need to try something different.

Comment: @JerryHolmes Think more carefully. Here is a hint: the answer is neither $0$ nor $\infty$.

Comment: Actually, when $x$ goes to $0$, $\frac4{x^2}$ goes to $\infty$.

Comment: The answer is -2 or 2 dpends on wheter it goes from left or right,.,...hahah i realised

Comment: Now I will write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, $\lim_{x\to0+}x=0$ and $\lim_{x\to0+}\left(1+\frac{4}{x^2}\right)=\infty$. Because of this, you cannot use the limit theorems to compute the limit of the product using the product of the limits, since those theorems require that both limits in the product be finite.

You already thought about it and realized that the answer is either $-2$ and $2$, but for the sake of making sure, here is how you get the answer: $$\lim_{x\to0+}x\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{x^2}}=\lim_{x\to0+}\sqrt{x^2\left(1+\frac{4}{x^2}\right)}=\lim_{x\to0+}\sqrt{x^2+4}$$ Since the symbol $\sqrt{}$ denotes the nonnegative square root, the answer is indeed $2$ and not $-2$.

Comment: Hi what if x goes from left? Should the answer be -2 then? I am having a huge debate with my friends over it....They are saying they used Geogebra to simulate the graph of the function and it turns out if x goes from left than as x goes to 0, f=-2.....But what you wrote here makes sense too but that case its positive 2...So what should we do about this?

Comment: Hi there. In the case that $x$ approaches $0$ from the left, you would have that $$\lim_{x\to0-}x\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{x^2}}=-\lim_{x\to0-}(-x)\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{x^2}}=-\lim_{x\to0-}\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{x^2}}=-\lim_{x\to0-}\sqrt{x^2+4}=-\lim_{x\to0+}\sqrt{x^2+4}=-2.$$ So your friends are indeed correct. But since your question asks about approaching $0$ from the right, the answer is $2$ instead.

Comment: ah ok Thanks.....its kinda weird thou.....lol

Comment: @JerryHolmes This is all a consequence of the $\sqrt{}$ function being involved. It is not a very well-behaved function.

Answer (score -1):

Alternate approach:

Rewrite the problem to

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\left(1+\frac{4}{x^2}\right)^{\frac{1}2}}{(1/x)}$$

which puts it in the form $\displaystyle \frac{\infty}{\infty}.$ Then, invoke [L'Hopital's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule).

Taking the derivative of the numerator and denominator separately, you have

$$\frac{\frac{1}{2}\left[1 + \frac{4}{x^2}\right]^{-(1/2)} \left[4(-2)x^{(-3)}\right]}{- \frac{1}{x^2}}.\tag1 $$

(1) above can be re-written as :

$$\frac{\frac{1}{2}\left[1 + \frac{4}{x^2}\right]^{-(1/2)} \left[(-8)x^2\right]}{(-1)x^3}.\tag2 $$

(2) above can be re-written as :

$$\frac{4\left[1 + \frac{4}{x^2}\right]^{-(1/2)}}{x}.\tag3 $$

(3) above can be re-written as :

$$\frac{4\left[\frac{x^2 + 4}{x^2}\right]^{-(1/2)}}{x}.\tag4 $$

(4) above can be re-written as :

$$\frac{4\left[x^2\right]^{(1/2)}}{x(x^2 + 4)^{(1/2)}}.\tag5 $$

Noting that the limit is being taken as $x \to 0^+$ 
(i.e. $x$ is approaching $0$ from the *positive* side) 
(5) above can be re-written as :

$$\frac{4}{(x^2 + 4)^{(1/2)}}.\tag6 $$

Noting that $$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \sqrt{x^2 + 4} = 2, $$

you are left with

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{4}{\sqrt{x^2 + 4}} = \frac{4}{2} = 2.$$